# How to make Inline expression in javascript wait before executing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, eval

I have an expression `<%= GetAddPinScript() %>` that evaluates a method in my code-behind file. The method generates javascript which it then returns:
`AddPushpin('data', 'more data', numbers, numbers, 'no');`

The key here is that `'no'` is a variable inserted by the code-behind method and helps the rest of my javascript determine if some content should display or not.(basically a bool)

The problem I'm having is that the method in my code-behind needs a variable(`result` in the below code) that is sent through an ajax call **before** the expression is evaluated in order to determine the correct variable to generate in the javascript -- but the expression always evaluates on the page load.

So how can I prevent the expression from being evaluated before the ajax call is made?

Javascript

```
function displayGeneralInfo(specifics)
     {
     var callback = AddQueryString(window.location.href, "action", "displayResults");
     $.ajax({
            url: callback,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                specifics: specifics
                }
                });
                <%= GetAddPinScript() %>
     }
```

and the AddPushpin function

```
function AddPushpin(name, description, latitude, longitude, selected) {
    // Add a pin to the map
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center, null);

    if(selected !== null || selected!="")
      {
      if(selected == "yes")
       {
       infoboxOptions = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(center,
        {                          width: 285,
                               height: 170,
                               visible:true,
                               actions:[{label: 'Associate', eventHandler: associate}]
                               });
                               map.entities.push(infoboxOptions);
        }
    }
    map.entities.push(pin);
}
```

and the code-behind snippet

```
public string GetAddPinScript()
    {
foreach (Location location in foo(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Longitude) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Latitude)))
        {
            selected = "no";
            if (!result.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                if (location.MapPinDescription.IndexOf(result) > 0)
                    selected = "yes";
            }
            pins.Add(string.Format("AddPushpin('{0}', '{1}', {2}, {3}, '{4}');",
                location.etc1("'", @"\'"), location.etc2("'", @"\'"), location.etc3, location.etc4, selected));
           string retVal = string.Join("\n", pins.ToArray());
           return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make it wait. The javascript is executed on the client and this function runs on the server. Asp.net does all the binding before it sends data to the client so there is no way you can say wait till some code runs on client and then run this function. I suggest you call this function when the ajax call is made to the server. Return some html from this function and then include this in your html in the success function.

Comment: Thanks, I was banging my head against the wall trying to find an answer. Is it possible to have the ajax call return the function(s) and then execute that?

Comment: You can execute the function in the ajax call you make. Make your rest api return some html and then in your success function just put that html in your page html. For eg. You make a ajax call to url /xyz, this request will be hanled by some action on your controller. Call your function GetAddPinScript from this action and then return some html from your action like <script>AddPushpin('data', 'more data', numbers, numbers, 'no');</script>. Then in your success function of your ajax append this script tag to the end of the body tag

Answer (score 0):

To have the add pin script run after the ajax call is complete, you should set it as the complete handler of the ajax call:

```
function displayGeneralInfo(specifics)
 {
 var callback = AddQueryString(window.location.href, "action", "displayResults");
 $.ajax({
        url: callback,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
            specifics: specifics
            }
            },
        complete:  <%= GetAddPinScript() %>
 });
```

Note that the above syntax assumes that `GetAddPinScript` will return a function, either a name of an existing function or an anonymous function block.